# What concepts do I need to learn to achieve following scenario?

Tags: java, parallel-processing, mapreduce, distributed-computing

May be I am thinking loud here but how can I run a simple java program (with no other dependencies) on different computers (no parallel processing is required) as per following conditions:

1. I have a set of data. Let's say data is in `.txt` file.
2. I also have a simple java program (see below) that uses this data as input.
3. Now I have 10 computers.Let's call them nodes.
4. I have to run java program on each nodes (nodes are independent to each other) and gets back the output from each of them and save it 
    into another `txt`. Let's say `output.txt`. It could be like reducing part of mapping-reducing tech.

And here is my thought on it:

1. Divide the data into small `.txt`(s). I have already done this
2. Install the Java program at each node by extracting it into `.jar`. Already done this

Now what next I have to do to achieve it? I am rookie in Parallel Processing and MPI. Just need some guidance on it.

Thanks for your help in Advance :)

And here the Java program:

```
import java.io.*;

public class CopyFile {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {

        FileInputStream in = null;
        FileOutputStream out = null;

        try {

            in = new FileInputStream("input.txt");
            out = new FileOutputStream("output.txt");
            int c;

            while ((c = in.read()) != -1) {
                 // want to do some computation. Let's say finding prime number
            }

        } finally {

            if (in != null) {
                in.close();
            }

            if (out != null) {
                out.close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why negative? Feedback is required..

Comment: What you just described sounds a lot like parallel processing... Also its not clear what you are asking, please revise and clarify

Comment: @MuhammadHijazi FYI It's not a parallel processing. How can you even think of it when I have already mentioned that "No parallel processing required". Also, I am collecting the data from each node . All nodes are independent to each other.

Please read it carefully before down voting it SIR!!

In parallel processing all nodes will be connected to each other

Comment: parallel processing doesn't necessarily need to involve one computer running multiple processes, it can be done over a network. What you are describing is taking a bunch of data, sending it to (in your own words) a bunch of nodes, having those nodes process that data in parallel, and then returning an output. That is parallel programming. Also I did not down vote your question, that was someone else so please relax, i'm only trying to help.

Comment: He could use a sort of P2P network where the nodes share the results with one another... or have a server-client architecture where he sits at one node and distributes the text from that point.

Comment: No! I didn't mention that data will be execute in parallel. Please let me know where i wrote it?

Comment: To make sure I understand, you want to take data, split it up, and have it processed by multiple nodes, that then return the processed data to a base node to be reassembled/processed/outputed, correct?

Comment: @MuhammadHijazi Absolutely and Thanks

Comment: Then that is a form of parallel processing. Each node is processing data at the same time as other nodes are processing data. It doesn't matter if the nodes communicate with each other as long as they are processing data at the same time it is considered parallel. Make sense?

Comment: Actually all nodes are not processing data at the same time. All of them are independent to each other and can process the data at any time (depends on their computer resource allocation)

Comment: Regardless, the idea is you split up your data to multiple nodes, each of them processes independently of the others and then returns the output to a source where it is then output, this IS parallel programming since you are running multiple nodes in parallel of each other.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64713/discussion-between-muhammad-hijazi-and-amit-pal).

Comment: So any guidance or suggestion to achieve it. Any sub-topics of parallel processing?

Answer (score 1):

You're contradicting yourself with "no parallel processing is required" you're actually defining your problem as being [embarrassingly parallel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embarrassingly_parallel), this means that no synchronisation between the nodes is required.

After the part what you've already done (installing java, copy the file) you only would need to start the program. And with 10 nodes you might be faster doing this with a shell or python script which just would visit each node, but with an increasing number of nodes it gets more and more complicated, that's why you have Hadoop/YARN or MPI to deal with this issue for you.

For instance in MPI would have a master node and N slaves. The master would read the file and sent it line by line to the slaves. After it has done it, it could receive and concatenate the answers from the slaves, which would be, the same as what you want to write inside the output.txt.

If you look at it as a Map/Reduce job, you're again wrong, since this would be the mapping part. The file would be split as input between your nodes by Hadoop or Spark and you would check each input like for what ever you want to check it for. Afterwards you would emit the interesting lines, or some other data. You can skip in most systems the Reduce part, which is what you want to do, and would just have the result from mapping concatenated again.

Comment: Agreed! I will use with MPI in master and slave